# What are the results of element.focus() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, focus

So i am new to javascript and I searched a lot about the focus function's results but all I find is that it is to focus on elements. This explanation is not really helping me, so can someone explain to me what is the difference on the results when using this function? What does it mean that it focuses on certain elements?

Comment: Which `focus` function are you talking about? The [`focus` method of HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus)?

Comment: the example that im checking now is focusing through DOM,

document.getElementById(id).focus();

so yes basically for html elements i think

Answer (score 0):

You have an exemple here : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_blur
When you press enter on a form for example, it will validate the form if you have the focus on the button "submit" but it won't it you don't have the focus on it.

Also for an input, you can write something in it if you have the focus on it but not if you don't.

This function is used to give focus to an element.

Comment: thank you now it's pretty clear, but what about when it comes to textarea that the user needs to fill? makes the letters bold or something?

Comment: nope, it just put the focus on the textarea. Then, the way the textarea change when it gets the focus depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - the element becomes the first responder to any UI interaction e.g. keyboard / mouse etc.

The long answer - the behaviour of how elements work when focused is documented in the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-focus). In particular, take a look at the [focusing steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focusing-steps)

> 1. If the element is not in a Document, or if the element's Document has no browsing context, or if the element's Document's browsing context has no top-level browsing context, or if the element is not focusable, or if the element is already focused, then abort these steps.
> 2. If focusing the element will remove the focus from another element, then run the unfocusing steps for that element.
> 3. Make the element the currently focused element in its top-level browsing context.
>
>    Some elements, most notably area, can correspond to more than one distinct focusable area. If a particular area was indicated when the element was focused, then that is the area that must get focus; otherwise, e.g. when using the focus() method, the first such region in tree order is the one that must be focused.
> 4. The user agent may apply relevant platform-specific conventions for focusing widgets.
>
>    *For example, some platforms select the contents of a text field when that field is focused*.
> 5. Fire a simple event named focus at the element.